# Create pdf graphs of data if ID is the same

Tags: r, pdf, graph, find

I need a loop for R Studio that will create a couple distributions for variables `t1`,`t2`, and `t_all` that have the same ID number. The data is all listed in one table. Example data from csv file.

df:

```
ID  Date    EPOCH   t1  t2  t_all
000111  011713  1   32  NA  32
000111  011513  5   33  NA  33
000111  010813  4   32  30  32
000111  010113  1   31  NA  31
000111  012113  2   29  NA  29
000111  010313  3   NA  34  34                  
000112  010313  2   28  NA  28
000112  010313  2   38  NA  38
000112  012913  3   51  NA  51
000112  011513  5   161 NA  161
000112  012213  5   32  NA  32
000112  011113  4   33  NA  33                  
000121  011113  1   31  NA  31
000121  011713  3   30  NA  30
000121  011513  5   32  NA  32
000121  010813  4   NA  30  30
000121  010113  2   28  34  31
000121  010513  3   28  NA  28
000121  010313  1   32  NA  32              
000134  010513  5   30  30  30
000134  011113  4   28  NA  28
000134  011713  1   NA  31  31
000134  011513  3   NA  36  36
000134  010813  2   33  29  31
000134  010113  1   30  33  31
000134  010513  1   37  NA  37
```

So the loop needs to be able to search to find all data rows with the same ID then plot them separately as a histogram, pdf, and cdf.

Final output should be:

```
Graph 1 : ID000111 Histogram
Graph 2 : ID000111 PDF
Graph 3 : ID000111 CDF
Graph 4 : ID000112 Histogram
Graph 5 : ID000112 PDF
etc.
```

or all the histograms first then all the pdf but everything needs to be separate.

Example Ecdf
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat the ID numbers as factors and use a for-loop to plot graphs for each factor

```
dfunique<-unique(df$ID)
fac<-as.factor(dfunique$x)
for (f in fac) {
    temp<-subset(df,ID==f)
    if (nrow(temp)==0)next

    name<-paste(paste(f, "hist", sep="-"),"png", sep=".")
    png(name)
    #my hist code
    hist(temp$t_all,breaks=100,freq=FALSE)
    dev.off()

    #do similar for pdf, cdf

    name<-paste(paste(f, "pdf", sep="-"),"png", sep=".")
    png(name)
    #my pdf code
    plot(density(temp$t_all))
    dev.off()

    name<-paste(paste(f, "cdf", sep="-"),"png", sep=".")
    png(name)
    #my ecdf code
     plot(ecdf(temp$t_all))
    dev.off()
 }
```